# I don't know why but I cant pull or clone on git

Tags: git, github

I've been trying cloning or fetching on git but it always end up being cut off. When i try git branch -r, its not even updated. Also when I try fetching all the remotes still it won't work. Is github still down because of the attack? I look at their status they said everything is working normally. Please kindly help me solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need some more information to look for a solution. When you say "it won't work" what error messages are you getting? Are you working in the command line, the Github GUI client, etc.? I'm working on a Github-hosted project right now with no errors or problems, so Github is definitely up and running.

Comment: I am using git and github. when i tried fetching our work in our private repo through git it will only on Receiving objects: 53%(71/133), 10.63 Mib | 3.00 Kibsthen it will stop there. fatal: index-packed failed(71/133) , 11.32 Mib | 7.00 KiB/s. so what do you think the problem?

Comment: kindly add all these details into the question

Comment: @shaktimaan Sorry took so long to reply. I thank you for concerning with my question. </br>I deleted my local file from our repo (so that I start new) then when I tried clonning it again. </br> git clone https://github.com/andigylle23/EnglishDevelop </br> Clonning to 'EnglishDevelop'... </br> remote: Counting objects: 5607, done. </br>remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3255/3255), done. </br> Receiving objects: 53%(873/5607), 1.18 Mib | 8.00 KiBs</br>fatal: index-packed failed. is it internet problem?

Comment: @user3370502 If this is a big repo you are downloading, and the clone fails (doesn't finish off completely), then next time, do a `git pull origin master` instead of cloning it afresh every time.

Answer (score 0):

`fatal: index-packed failed` would usually point to a Github server error, but like you say, their status page says that all systems are operational. Could also be an issue with your own internet connection.

Is it a public project? I can try cloning it myself and see what happens.

Comment: sorry took so long to answer. no its a private but thank you so much. I appreciate it. Maybe because of our internet connection, I really don't know. We have schedule update but we can't since all of us can't use git and github. even downloading the .zip files don't allow us but other usage of the internet were fine.